# How does Ubsoft's app "ctOS mobile", work from the main Watch_Dogs player's perspective?

Tags: watch-dogs

I'm trying to get my head around how my interaction on the [ctOS app for iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/watch-dogs-companion-ctos/id714196271?mt=8) appears for people playing the main [Watch_Dogs](http://watchdogs.ubi.com/watchdogs/en-gb/home/index.aspx) game.

The app seems to allow me to control the helicopter and police response in someone else's game.  However, it also seems to enable me to control things like bridges, road spikes and various other hackable objects in their world.  This would be quite invasive if the Watch_Dogs player wasn't expecting it:

- Does the Watch_Dogs player get a chance to confirm the interaction?
- Does the interaction only occur during certain side-missions, could it occur at any time, or is it a separate activity within Watch_Dogs?
- Does the interaction have to be unlocked somehow within the main Watch_Dogs game, or is it available from the first mission?

Comment: What I would like to know, is how to control the helicopter etc.  Is it only on iPhone?  Do you have to have the console game? etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The person playing Watch_Dogs on PC/PS/XBox gets an on screen prompt indicating that somebody is challenging them.

[image]

This prompt is only possible outside of missions, like the Fixer missions. Online modes only become available after completing the first few story missions up to and including the Online Contracts Introduction (which is when you first go through the tutorial for the one on one hacking missions).

Answer (score 2):

You can only interact with other player games by "intruding" another player for a hacking mission or a race or any other of the available intrusion types.
When you are hacking someone else's game, their job is to stop you from doing so, therefore all the hacking you do in their game has no confirmations.

The online modes are available few missions into the game when you get "hacked" by an AI player as a tutorial. Online interactions can be disabled within the options if so desired.